# Getting a map property from environment variable with Spring

Tags: java, spring, environment-variables

I'm creating a microservice with Spring Boot that uses some properties loaded both with `@Value` and `@ConfigurationProperties`. Those properties will have default values defined in the `application.yaml` but I want to override them with environment variables. I've manage to do it with almost every basic property type but I'm unable with maps.

This is the code that retrieves the property, so the map is found in `configuration.map`:

```java
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "configuration")
public class MapConfig{
    private Map<String, Object> map;
}
```

The default values I have in the `application.yaml` are:

```
configuration:
  map:
    a: "A"
    b: 2
    c: true
```

This works fine and I get a map containing those key-value entries. Problem comes when I try to initialize the map with the environment variables. I've tried with multiples variants of `CONFIGURATION_MAP='{aa:"aa", bb:12, cc:true}'` and every time I start the application I get the default values defined in `application.yaml` but no trace of the environment map.

I also tried adding variables like `CONFIGURATION_MAP_AA='HELLO'` and I was able to put new values in my map. However all I can do is adding information but the default values I wrote in the yaml are still there. In this case I'm getting:

```
{
    "aa": "HELLO",
    "a": "A",
    "b": 2,
    "c": true
}
```

This isn't the behavior I'm looking for. I want to completely override the default map instead of adding new info. It also has the problem that keys added this way are always transformed to lowercase so I can't override keys with camelCase. And values are also casted to strings even when my map is `<String,Object>`.

Can anyone tell me how to properly initialize maps with environment variables or point me in the right direction? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the order in which the properties are been loaded. 
Have a look at this [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) that explains the loading order. I don't know if it will be 
useful for your scenario but you can try creating a profile (for example `application-other.yml`) and load this. It will load after the `application.yml`

The cast is coming from the most general type in your list. In the end all three "`name`, `1`, `true`" can be Strings. I can't think of a way of loading `Object` but you can recast your String on what you like ( if its needed. ) Else break it into multiple maps that are type specific ( `Map<String,String> , Map<String,Boolean>, Map<String,Integer>` )

Comment: I don't think the problem is the order. The application is looking for the properties in the environment variables and only examines the `application.yaml` when any of them is missing. For example if I set the key 'a' with a value 'yaml' in the `application.yaml` and with a value `env` in the environment variable the final value will be `env`. The problem is that even after finding some keys in my environment it still resorts to the local properties. Even after using an `application-profile.yaml` I still reproduce the same problem.

Comment: Incase you didnt try it for the profile to load you have to declare it (example when you run the program -Dspring.profiles.active=profileName ) . The default profile will always be loaded so its not like it resorts to the local properties than always loading them. A suggestion is 1. start by removing the file and see what it loads.  2. Load a profile without the default and see if the profile overrides your environment. 3. re-add the default to check which is superior. 
As a workaround you can use environment variables in your application-profile.yml (they are used like ${var_name}) to inject

Comment: I had an `application-dev.yaml` with _a_ and _b_ and an `application.yaml` with _a_, _b_ and _c_. I run the application with _dev_ profile and I got a map with _a_, _b_ and _c_. _a_ and _b_ have the values in the profile yaml and _c_ has the value in the default yaml. The order is the profile and then the generic, just like it's specified in the documentation. And, according to that and my own tests, environment variables are loaded before any of them. Using profiles doesn't help because I need environment variables, but even if I could it wouldn't solve my problem with maps. But thanks anyway

Comment: I think we confused something here ! According to the docs i send enviroment are loaded 9 and 10 while the yamls come after it. Thats why you get the variations. Secondly the map is NOT reseted because configurations are additive. So they replace only existing keys. Thats why it keeps adding. The application.yml should contain ONLY the bare minimal configuration that are shareable between your application instances. profiles should override / populate specifics. Last but not least. Environment variables still exist when yaml loads so you can do `map: ${mapValues} `to add them.(If json is supp)

Comment: And that is because environment is key:value based. Maps introduced to yml ( and an ugly implementation in xml ). So -in my opinion- profiles is the way to go for what you explained.

Comment: Yes, I think we are in the same page now :) About the second part, this is just a proof of concept but in the future I'll have the microservice deployed in multiple K8S pods and maybe I'd like to change the properties only for some of them. And I may need to run it with some particular values with Docker or similar. That's why I prefer environment variables over profiles. I've already solved this with K8S ConfigMaps so it's ok. About the technical problem (that exists no matter if I use profiles), it's due to the fact that configurations are additive, as you said.

Comment: I'm still trying to find a way to avoid later steps in the configuration setup to add new entries.  But I'm aware that it maybe not be possible (or at least I don't know how). Thing is I'm creating something that many other developers will use so I'm trying to restrain them the less I can. That's why I'm not happy with just saying to them a mere "you shouldn't haver more than the minimum". I'm still facing some other problems, though.

Comment: Thats why i mentioned the "configurable" profile.. Did you give it a try cause i am really curious if the map can be configured that way. If yes then you have a solution. You deploy everything with your placeholder profile that will be filling the blanks from the environment!

Comment: I've tried, but Spring doesn't know how to convert from the expression `'{aa:"aa", bb:12, cc:true}'` to a `Map`. I can only initialize the keys one by one, which is pretty much the same as using the environment variables.

Comment: Ah sad. Thank you for trying and letting me know !

Comment: Thanks to you too :) I think I'll try some other approach